# Зачем нужны замыкания? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, замыкания

Коллеги! Теоретически я как бы понял сущность замыкания: это высшая функция, возвращающая другую, "дочернюю" функцию, при этом должны быть переменные, замкнутые в области видимости "между" высшей и дочерней. Дочерняя функция вызывается в глобальной области и обрабатывает эти переменные и свои аргументы. Как бы создается один пакет из двух "набираемых" в двух независимых вызовах кортежей данных.
ВОПРОС: а какова необходимость в замыкании, конкретно, какой род проблем оно решает, какой тип задач, для реализации какого алгоритма нужен?

Comment: А как пользоваться ооп не имея его?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю будет легче понять что это заглянув в историю. Сегодня конечно имея дополнительные конструкции языка это может казаться бесмысленным.

Кусочек текста [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures)

```js
function makeFunc() {
  var name = "Mozilla";
  function displayName() {
    alert(name);
  }
  return displayName;
};

var myFunc = makeFunc();
myFunc();
```

> **Замыкания на практике.**
>
> Замыкания полезны тем, что позволяют связать данные (лексическое
> окружение) с функцией, которая работает с этими данными. *Очевидна
> параллель с объектно-ориентированным программированием, где объекты
> позволяют нам связать некоторые данные (свойства объекта) с одним или
> несколькими методами.*
>
> Следовательно, замыкания можно использовать везде, где вы обычно
> использовали объект с одним единственным методом.
>
> Такие ситуации повсеместно встречаются в web-разработке. Большое
> количество front-end кода, который мы пишем на JavaScript, основано на
> обработке событий. Мы описываем какое-то поведение, а потом связываем
> его с событием, которое создаётся пользователем (например, клик мышкой
> или нажатие клавиши). При этом наш код обычно привязывается к событию
> в виде обратного/ответного вызова (callback): callback функция -
> функция выполняемая в ответ на возникновение события.
>
> Языки вроде Java позволяют нам объявлять частные (private) методы .
> Это значит, что они могут быть вызваны только методами того же класса,
> в котором объявлены.
>
> JavaScript не имеет встроенной возможности сделать такое, но это можно
> эмулировать с помощью замыкания. Частные методы полезны не только тем,
> что ограничивают доступ к коду, это также мощное средство глобальной
> организации пространства имён, позволяющее не засорять публичный
> интерфейс вашего кода внутренними методами классов